# libgdx - Render two textures side by side using SpriteBatch and use one camera

Tags: libgdx, textures, sprite, spritebatch

I want to render two textures side by side. And then consider such combination of these two textures as one sprite to use a single camera. I am able to render two textures side by side using SpriteBatch. How do I make the combination of these two textures into a single sprite and use camera to get different views?

Currently after I drew two textures with SpriteBatch, I'm trying to draw such SpriteBatch with a sprite. But I'm getting nullpointer when calling sprite.draw().

My ultimate goal is to render two images side by side to use as a background, and be able to use a camera on my background. Any ideas? THX

My current code:

```
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    //create two texture for 1.jpg and 2.jpg
    //use batch to draw them separately at different position
    img_1 = new Texture("1.jpg"); 
    img_2 = new Texture("2.jpg"); 

    mWorld = new Sprite();
    mWorld.setPosition(0, 0);
    mWorld.setSize(WORLD_WIDTH,WORLD_HEIGHT);
    float aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_WIDTH * aspectRatio);
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2f, camera.viewportHeight / 2f, 0);
    camera.update();
}

@Override
public void render () {
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(this.img_1, 0, 0, WORLD_WIDTH/2, WORLD_HEIGHT);
    batch.draw(this.img_2, WORLD_WIDTH/2, 0, WORLD_WIDTH/2, WORLD_HEIGHT);

    //getting java nullpointer exception here
    mWorld.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: have you set a texture for the sprite mWorld? I don't see anything, also post the full stackTrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprite is simply a wrapper (to add more functionality) for a single Texture (or TextureRegion).

You just call "new Sprite();" which creates a sprite with no texture (so nothing to draw, no image information, etc), thus you get a null pointer exception when you try to draw the sprite.

Since you want to combine two textures, why not create a single texture (image) with an external tool (like pain.net or gimp,..)?

If you want to draw two textures as a single object, you need to create your own class, for example:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class TestGame extends ApplicationAdapter
{

    public class TwoTextures
    {
        private final Texture   tex1, tex2;
        private final float     pos1X, pos1Y, pos2X;

        public TwoTextures(Texture tex1, Texture tex2, float posX, float posY)
        {
            this.tex1 = tex1;
            this.tex2 = tex2;
            this.pos1X = posX;
            this.pos1Y = posY;

            this.pos2X = posX + tex1.getWidth();
        }

        public void draw(Batch batch)
        {
            batch.draw(tex1, pos1X, pos1Y);
            batch.draw(tex2, pos2X, pos1Y);
        }

        public void dispose()
        {
            tex1.dispose();
            tex2.dispose();
        }
    }

    OrthographicCamera  camera;

    Batch               batch;

    TwoTextures         background;

    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();

        background = new TwoTextures(
                new Texture("1.jpg"),
                new Texture("2.jpg"),
                0,
                0);
    }

    @Override
    public void render()
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        {
            background.draw(batch);
        }
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
        batch.dispose();
        background.dispose();
    }
}
```